# How to force cloudfront to cache only every 5 seconds instead of 24 hours for dynamic content

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

`My desired behavior is to have cloudfront cache my origin(api endpoint that returns json).`

It seems like no matter what values I put in the header for max-age at my origin or what "ttl" values I put in my cloudfront distribution, hitting the  distribution point caches for 24 hours in cloudfront when using curl with a php backend.  When hitting the endpoint through Chrome it is cached every 5 seconds like desired.(I think chrome is sending no-cache in the request header)

Does anyone have a recommendation on how to force cloudfront to cache fresh data every 5 seconds on my site especially when using curl?

I am effectively hitting a rest api point that is sending json back that needs to be dynamically cached in cloudfront every five seconds.  The cache needs to be refreshed after 5 seconds so fresh data is served even if the data is the same.  The origin is dynamic content that changes every hour on the hour and is not static.

Is it impossible to get passed the 24 hour caching limit?

I Tried different Cache-Control headers like max-age and s-maxage
I Tried changing the ttl times in my cloudfront distrubtuion

I have set Object caching to Customize and:

```
Min TTL is 0
Max TTL is 5
Default TTL is 5
```

My origin headers are:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 09 May 2019 14:15:17 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.39 (cPanel) OpenSSL/1.0.2r mod_bwlimited/1.4 mpm-itk/2.4.7-04
Last-Modified: Thu, 09 May 2019 14:12:57 GMT
ETag: "e1ab8bae1d38bfceecece2c36df378c1-gzip"
X-Robots-Tag: noindex, follow
Link: <https://www.example.com/json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
Cache-Control: max-age=5
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 789
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json
```

Comment: Do I need to select:  Use Origin Cache Headers and do I need to send last modified in the header?

Comment: This is not expected behavior.  Can you provide an example URL that exhibits the behavior?